# How can I see the command that TeXworks is using and emulate this using pdflatex on the command line

Tags: pdftex, texworks, python

I've written a program to automate generation of pdf files. In my python script I use pdflatex and call this with a command line package:

command:

```
pdflatex --interaction=batchmode my_file.tex |
```

When i open this pdf file it is not the same as if I open the my_file.tex file in TeXworks and the pdf is generated this way. I'm a LaTeX newbie so even though I understand that this must be a configuration difference in my pdflatex command and the command TeXworks is using, I don't know how to find out the command in TeXworks, and emulate this to pdflatex.

In TeXworks the dropdown 'config' is set at pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX

any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated as I've searched but cannot seem to find anything I understand on this!

Thanks

Comment: `pdflatex --interaction=batchmode my_file;makeindex my_file; bibtex my_file; pdflatex --interaction=batchmode my_file` possibly works you might need an additional pdftex run, presumably you can see exactly what texwors does for taht option in its config settings

Comment: but you only need makeidex if the files have index entries and only need bibtex if they reference a `.bib` bilbliography database, do your python generated files do either?